# How can i change superfish chilled nav menus font color

Tags: css, menu, drupal-7, theming

I was created this menu using superfish module and i was tying to change the chilled menus font-color to make different from the parent font-color.  i wast trying to do something using firebug and I spending more time to trying to edit the  css style but can't found it the exact class of the nav-menu font color. 
there is a class called `.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar a {`  under the style I'm using is pomegranate.css 
when I change this color the parent and the chilled color are changed

Demo : http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample4
style I'm using

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar {
  width: 100%;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate a {
  border: 1px outset #68000e;
  color: #ffebee;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate a.sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.rtl a.sf-with-ul {
  padding-left: 2.25em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar a {
  border: 0;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate span.sf-description {
  color: #13a;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar {
  background-image: url(../images/topmenu.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #A60405; 
  text-decoration: none;  
  height: 30px;
  }
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li li{
  background: #6c0019;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li li li {
  background: #5f0016;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li:hover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sfHover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.active a,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate a:focus,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate a:hover,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate a:active,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar li li {
  background-image: url(../images/menu2.gif); 
  background-color: #E6E4E4;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  color: #C80F0F;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar li ul {
  background-image: url(../images/menu2.gif);
  background-color: #E6E4E4;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.sf-navbar li ul li ul {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate ul.sf-megamenu li.sf-megamenu-wrapper ol,
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate ul.sf-megamenu li.sf-megamenu-wrapper ol li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate ul.sf-megamenu li.sf-megamenu-wrapper a.menuparent {
        font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate ul.sf-megamenu li.sf-megamenu-wrapper ol li.sf-megamenu-column {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        width: 12em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate.rtl ul.sf-megamenu li.sf-megamenu-wrapper ol li.sf-megamenu-column {
        float: right;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-1 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 12em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-2 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 24em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-3 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 36em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-4 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 48em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-5 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 60em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-6 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 72em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-7 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 84em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-8 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 96em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-9 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 108em;
}
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li.sf-parent-children-10 ul.sf-megamenu {
        width: 120em;
}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to style an image, you should provide some code. If this question is a pure, how do I style this HTML, you should ask at at StackOverflow, as this site is for Drupal questions, not CSS questions.

Comment: @googletorp I thought it is on drupal and it is a drupal module.

Comment: @jone, it's almost impossible to answer a practical CSS question without seeing the relevant HTML. I'd suggest something like: `#parentMenuID li .subMenuUlClass .subMenuLiClass {...}` but without seeing your HTML I don't know *what* to suggest specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your html markup, it seems like you'd want to add color to:

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li li{
  background: #6c0019;
}
```

which would become:

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-pomegranate li li{
  background: #6c0019;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```